# gdb7.5 print utf8 string show string address not string content

Tags: utf-8, gdb

I have just installed the latest released gdb--gdb7.5。 when i used it to debug the c++ program which is encoded with utf-8, i set the gdb charset to utf8 with the command" set charset utf-8". However when i want to print a string : `char *str = "明天是个好天气"` , the "p str" result is the address of the string rather than the content. So is there anyting necessary for gdb to debug utf8 string?

Breakpoint 1, test () at test.cpp:6

6           char *str = "我们的世界多么美好";

(gdb) n

8           printf( "%s\n" , str );

(gdb) p str

$1 = 0x40067c "0\221们2\204265\214321016好"

(gdb) set charset UTF-8

(gdb) show charset

The host character set is "UTF-8".
The target character set is "UTF-8".
The target wide character set is "auto; currently UTF-32".

(gdb) p str

$2 = 0x40067c

(gdb)

Answer (score 2):

Tell us **exactly** what you did, and **exactly** what GDB prints.

Using gdb-7.5:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5     char *str = "明天是个好天气";
(gdb) n

6     return 0;
(gdb) p str
$1 = 0x4005cc "明天是个好天气"

(gdb) show charset 
The host character set is "auto; currently UTF-8".
The target character set is "auto; currently UTF-8".
The target wide character set is "auto; currently UTF-32".

(gdb) set charset utf
Undefined item: "utf".
```

This shows that:

- GDB does the right thing "out of the box" for me.
- You likely didn't do `set charset utf`, but did something else.

Your `LANG` setting in the environment is relevant. Mine is:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

If I `unset LANG`, I get:

```
(gdb) p str
$1 = 0x4005cc "\346\230\216\345\244\251\346\230\257\344\270\252\345\245\275\345\244\251\346\260\224"
```

Comment: @RedLv Please put this into your question (with formatting) and delete your comment.